# if statement in jinja2 when pass a variable from post html

Tags: python, if-statement, post, flask, jinja2

When i pass a variable from post to template, i want to check it with if statement, if it is "`true`", the problem is, the if statement not work in **Jinja** and i can't find why.

http://127.0.0.1:5000/?flag=true%0A&user=xaris%0A

**Jinja code:**

```
    {% set flagt = request.args.get('flag')   %}
    {% set sign = true  %}
    {% if flagt is sameas sign  %}
    <div>blah blah blah blah</div>
    {% else %}
    <div>{{ flagit }}</div>
    {% endif %}*
```

Comment: `{% if flagt == 'true' %}` is what you want.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @snakechamberb's comments:  The issue that you are having is that request arguments come in as strings.  So, when you compare request parameter values, you can't compare them boolean true / false, you have to compare them to string `true` and string `false`.  e.g.,

```
{% set flagt = request.args.get('flag')   %}
{% set sign = true  %}
{% if flagt.lower() in ('true', '1') %}
<div>blah blah blah blah</div>
{% else %}
<div>{{ flagt }}</div>
{% endif %}*
```